# xarray: preprocess for nearest Lat/Lon non-NaN variable

Tags: python, geospatial, python-xarray

Each `latitude`/`longitude` location in the dataset is associated with typically one `sss` value per day. I would like to retrieve the `sss` value nearest to a specified location on a given day. For example, find the `sss` value nearest to `latitude=-89.88` and `longitude=-179.9` on `01/01/2014`.

Each daily file is around 20MB, and I'd like to do this over 10 years.

URL: https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/data/socd1/coastwatch/products/miras/nc/SM_D2014001_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 1, altitude: 1, latitude: 720, longitude: 1440, nv: 2)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-01-01T12:00:00
  * altitude   (altitude) float64 0.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -89.88 -89.62 -89.38 ... 89.38 89.62 89.88
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -179.9 -179.6 -179.4 ... 179.4 179.6 179.9
Dimensions without coordinates: nv
Data variables:
    coord_ref  int32 ...
    time_bnds  (time, nv) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(1, 2), meta=np.ndarray>
    sss        (time, altitude, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1, 720, 1440), meta=np.ndarray>
    sss_dif    (time, altitude, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1, 720, 1440), meta=np.ndarray>
    l2_time    (time, altitude, latitude, longitude) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1, 720, 1440), meta=np.ndarray>
    l2_lat     (time, altitude, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1, 720, 1440), meta=np.ndarray>
    l2_lon     (time, altitude, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1, 720, 1440), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes: (12/39)
    history:                       Wed Feb 20 18:15:04 2019\n: /data/data001/...
    title:                         Sea Surface Salinity - Near Real Time - Mi...
    product_name:                  SM_D2014001_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc
    source:                        European Space Agency(ESA)
    platform:                      PROTEUS
    instrument:                    Microwave Imaging Radiometer with Aperture...
    ...                            ...
    Summary:                       CoastWatch/OceanWatch Level-3 SSS products...
    Input Files:                   /data/data001/repository/SMOS/ESA_restrict...
    cdm_data_type:                 Grid
    product_version:               662
    time_coverage_start:           2014-01-01T00:08:52Z
    time_coverage_stop:            2014-01-02T00:23:10Z
```

I can kind of get this to work, but the `sss` value is being returned as NaN.

```py
import xarray as xr
from functools import partial

def _preprocess(x):
  # return the nearest location that has non-NaN sss 
  return x.where(x['sss'].notnull()).sel(
    longitude=-179.9, latitude=-89.88, method='nearest')

partial_func = partial(_preprocess)

ds = xr.open_mfdataset("*.nc", preprocess=partial_func)
```

Returns:

| index | time | altitude | sss | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2014-01-01 12:00:00 | 0.0 | NaN | -86.44 | -170.1 |

Whereas I would like something like this:

| index | time | altitude | sss | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2014-01-01 12:00:00 | 0.0 | 27.1 | -82.28 | -169.9 |

Rather than utilizing `open_mfdataset`, this functionality can be implemented on a day-by-day, file-by-file basis. For example, utilizing geopandas:

```py
import geopandas

ds = xr.open_dataset('SM_D2014001_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc')

a = ds.to_dataframe().reset_index()
a = a[~a.sss.isna()]
a['LL'] = a['latitude'].astype(str) + a['longitude'].astype(str)

locs = a[['latitude', 'longitude']].value_counts().reset_index()
locs['LL'] = locs['latitude'].astype(str) + locs['longitude'].astype(str)

gdf1 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
  locs,
  geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(locs.longitude, locs.latitude),
  crs="EPSG:4326"
)
gdf1 = gdf1.to_crs(crs=3857)

gdf2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
  pd.DataFrame(), geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy([-179.9] [-89.88]),
  crs="EPSG:4326"
)
gdf2 = gdf2.to_crs(crs=3857)

dx = geopandas.sjoin_nearest(gdf2, gdf1, distance_col="distance",
  how='left')
a = a[a.LL.isin(dx['LL'])]
```

However, this is quite slow, hence the desire to utilize `preprocess` with `open_mfdataset`.

Using `.sel()` with bounds provides some improvement, for example:

```py
from functools import partial

def _preprocess(x, lon_bnds, lat_bnds):
  return x.sel(longitude=slice(*lon_bnds), latitude=slice(*lat_bnds))

lon_bnds, lat_bnds = (-130, -110), (26, 39)

partial_func = partial(_preprocess, lon_bnds=lon_bnds,
  lat_bnds=lat_bnds)

a = xr.open_mfdataset(['SM_D2014001_Map_SATSSS_data_1day.nc'],
  preprocess=partial_func)
```

**Edit:** Rather than using nearest, another option is simply to take the mean of all `sss` observations within a given Lat./Lon. rectangular region, per day. Using `open_mfdataset()` with one file at a time (one day at a time), per `.nc` file, `preprocess` can take a slice and then perform a mean for `sss` on the slice. This takes 1 minute to process 20 days' worth of files. However, using `open_mfdataset('*.nc', preprocess=partial_func)` should improve performance. For example,

```py
import xarray as xr
from functools import partial

def _preprocess(x, lon_bnds, lat_bnds):
  return x.sel(longitude=slice(*lon_bnds), latitude=slice(*lat_bnds))\
    .groupby('time').mean(...)
    
lon_bnds, lat_bnds = (-123, -111), (26.5, 38.5)

partial_func = partial(_preprocess, lon_bnds=lon_bnds,
  lat_bnds=lat_bnds)

ds = xr.open_mfdataset('*.nc', preprocess=partial_func)
```

Comment: Nice question. The issue has also been raised multiple times on Github, without an implemented solution yet (https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/644). One comment there mentions using a nearest neighbor interpolation as a workaround, however you would loose the information from which location you have choosen the non-nan value. Another, maybe tedious, idea I came up with: 1. For each lat-lon location sort the other locations by distance (by using haversine package for instance, do that once) 2. select location for a given day. If nan, move to the next nearest location from distance matrix.